# Can we interact and troubleshoot containers inside kubernetes without command line access?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-container

Can we interact and troubleshoot containers inside kubernetes without command line access? Or reading logs will be sufficient for debugging?
Is there any way for debugging the containers without command line (kubectl)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the containers created *FROM Scratch* are not simple to debug, the best you can do is add logging and telemetry in the container so that you don't have to debug it. The other option is use minimal images like busybox.

The K8s team has a [proposal](https://github.com/verb/community/blob/473c49d6cb75aa8f9fe3017bada74fe69206e18e/contributors/design-proposals/node/troubleshoot-running-pods.md) for a a `kubectl debug target-pod` command, but is not something you can use yet.

In the worse scenarios you can try  [Scratch-debugger](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/scratch-debugger/README.md), it will create a busybox pod in the same node your pod being debuged is and call docker to inject the filesystem into the existing container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up access to the dashboard and make changes to the containers / read logs there.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/